# Slavery in a Totalitarian Regime in the Middle Ages

Tags: society, medieval, slavery

What sort of task would slaves conduct in an imperialistic military regime during the middle ages? Would this be focus around military armament? Food production? Cheap troops? How would this impact society? What would be the economic impact?

Comment: You may want to look at [serfdom](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom).

Comment: They are similar but quite different.  Slavery: The man (and of course there were women slaves) who was enslaved in ancient times was considered to have died; all that was his passed to his master, including the power of life and death. The slave who resisted his master for any reason could be killed.

Comment: The serf, was a free man except for the obligations he owed to his lord and the rights his lord claimed over him. Both servile obligations and noble rights could be very extensive, but since the serf was a living creature with a soul, they could not be unlimited. The master could not deny his serf the amenities of the Church, work him on holy days, or demand actions of him that were immoral. The serf had the rights accorded him by natural law. He could resist a lord attempting to take his life or one attempting to withhold the necessities of life from him and his.

Comment: @Dynas In fact the master didn't have to allow him enough food to sustain himself or his family, and the serf and his family had no right to leave the area or refuse to work.  The serf had no right to hold weapons, and had no recourse to law.